# How can I delete 20% of total rows in cassandra using cqlsh

Tags: cassandra, delete-row

I am trying to delete multiple rows in cassandra cqlsh, but the query does not work, any ideas?

```
Delete from profile where key in (select key from profile where domain = 'personal');
```

Answer (score 3):

CQL does not allow for statements like you wrote above. You will need to write a script which performs one query in a paging manner and executes the deletes as needed.

Basically the process would be

```
Fetch a bunch of rows from Profile
Perform your filter
Delete those rows passing the filter
Fetch another bunch of rows
Repeat
```

For this I would recommend not using CQLSH and work more directly with a C* driver.